# Passing parameters to a event listener function in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, event-listener

Hello I have some code in which I take user input through in html and assign it to,two global variables

```
 var spursscoref = document.getElementById("spursscore").value;
 var livscoref = document.getElementById("livscore").value;
```

Which next show up in this addeventlistener function as parameters of the whowon function

```
var d = document.querySelector("#gut2");
d.addEventListener("click", function () {
whowon(spursscoref, livscoref, spurs, liverpool)
}, false);
```

The click event is meant to trigger the whowon function and pass in the parameters

```
function whowon(FirstScore, SecondScore, FirstTeam, SecondTeam) {

if (FirstScore > SecondScore) {

    FirstTeam.win();
    SecondTeam.lose();


} else if (FirstScore < SecondScore) {

    SecondTeam.win();


} else {

    FirstTeam.draw();
    SecondTeam.draw();
}

}
```

However the values are null,as I get a cannot read properties of null error on this line

var spursscoref = document.getElementById("spursscore").value;

I am pretty sure the problem is coming from the addlistener function,any help would be appreciated

Comment: The values aren't null. It says that you can't read properties ***of null***, which means that `getElementById()` is *returning* `null`. This is because the elements are not in the DOM when you try to fetch them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could do something like this -

```
$( document ).ready(function() {     

var d = document.querySelector("#gut2");
d.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var spursscoref = document.getElementById("spursscore").value;
  var livscoref = document.getElementById("livscore").value;
  whowon(spursscoref, livscoref, spurs, liverpool)
  }, false);

});
```

Wrap your code in $(document).ready(function(){}).  This will ensure that all of your DOM elements are loaded prior to executing your Javascript code.

Comment: Thanks it now works...how come it wasn't working before though?

Comment: @user3739465—read the first comment, it has your answer. You don't need jQuery, jus move the script element below the elements you're trying to access.

Comment: update your answer and delete comment. It is not clear when we read the answer alone.

Comment: I did not add include the  $( document ).ready(function() portion only the other bit.Still works though

Comment: Ok. Then it was a matter of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all of your code inside this

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

   //Your code here

});
```

My guess is that your code is executed before the html actually finished loading, causing it to return null.